# How to set directory of Xam.Plugin.Media to external storage in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I added the Xam.Plugin.Media to capture image. The problem is I want to save the picture to my SD Card if there is a SD Card and if not stick to the internal storage. How can I check if there is an sd card present? and if so, how can I get the directory?

My code below is the function to capture the image

```
 try
 {
     var cafNo = entCafNo.Text;

     await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

     if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
     {
         await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No Camera Available", "Ok");
         return;
     }
     var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
        new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            SaveToAlbum = true,
            Name = cafNo + "_IMG_01.png",
            CompressionQuality = 80,
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
            DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Front
        }
     );
     entPhoto1Url.Text = file.Path;

  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Console.Write(ex.Message);
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578913/how-to-detect-if-the-device-possess-an-sdcard

Comment: is there any way to do this in xamarin.forms?